# Regular Expression for " - " and characters after

Tags: regex, criteria

This is a question for experts on regular expressions, since it is something that I dont have much insight.

Its not C#, java specific, its a general regular expression that I need to put in one application that will rename files.

Basically I have structures of folders like this.

```
1 - I went to the cinema 1
   I went to the cinema 1 - movie title 1
   I went to the cinema 1 - movie title 2
   I went to the cinema 1 - movie title 3
   I went to the cinema 1 - movie title 4

2 - I went to the cinema 2
3 - I went to the cinema 3
```

I need an expression that pretty much returns the text after " - " because everything is before is the parent folder name.

May be a simple question but I did some search and I can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: Seriously, you searched for "Regular Expression for “ - ” and characters after" and gave up after no post answered exactly that question?

Comment: Yes I did, i think none of them works because of the space hyphen space

Comment: That's not my point. My point is that this is an extremely poor problem solving technique. You are supposed to *work it out yourself*, not google something that you can copy and paste and give up if that does not work immediately, just to turn to StackOverflow and let somebody else write something that you can copy and paste. Jeez, this really grinds my gears.

Comment: Go to https://regex101.com/ and http://www.regular-expressions.info/, (or a million other regex introductions and tutorials and examples) read about the basics of regex and tinker with it until you start to get the hang of it, and when you have something that kind of works but not completely, come here and ask an informed question about that one detail you don't quite understand. *That* is what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Regex is definetelly something that I want to learn more, however I don't control all the the characters and their purpose. I think that or I understand the big concept or i dont of Regex, and I think I dont have enough insight. Normally I dont use them, i can do other workarounds, but I think Stackoverflow is still free to ask questions. Thanks for the answers btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `-(.*)`, see [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM5iB0/1)

Comment: HI Thomas.

Thanks. It works there.
I am trying to use in one application called Bulk Rename Utility which change my files names based on REGEX, but must be application specific which not work there. In your live demo works fine.

Comment: Figured out the problem. Wasn't to do with regexes.
I tried that regex previosly but didnt work because Bulk Rename Utility needs an identifier like \1 to replace the regex. That is because we can use multiple regex. Let me edit the title, maybe will help somebody

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex, since the "-" character is not a special character used outside the square brackets.

You can use this `- *(.*)`
This is very similar to Thomas Ayoub answer, but I think you're not interested in the trailing space.

If you're sure that the space will always be there, and maybe you want to avoid other "-" inside the string to give unexpected results, you can use this: `- (.*)` (there's a space before the "-", so it will fine all the test after " - "

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/oB6wE1/1)